# Suggested method to watermark images on a case-by-case basis? (Matrix+CE Image or Channel Image)

Tags: conditionals, image, ce-image, channel-images

I want to add watermarks to *some* images that I upload to an EE site.

I create images/illustrations and want to watermark those. It's helpful when the images come up in Google Image Search, both for branding, to make copying more difficult, and to come up with a good branding strategy for Pinterest usage of images.

However, I also use images for which watermarking is not suitable (CC attribution images, images from other sites that I use with permission).

Right now I use the Matrix file upload and do resizing using CE image and  the image slug replacement method. I've theorized that I could add a switch in the Matrix field to watermark or not, and put CE image to work if the switch says yes.

However, I'm also thinking about re-architecting images using Channel Images instead. (call me crazy!)

1. For those of you who've worked with images using both CE Image and
   Channel Images, how would you conditionally apply watermarks using
   Channel Images?
2. Do you think I should stick to my current Matrix Image Replacement
   technique, or (once it's re-architected) would using Channel Images
   be easier to do in the long run?
3. Finally, is there some other method to accomplish watermarking on a
   case-by-case basis that I haven't mentioned here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't look to switch to a different method unless you have a particular need to. If I were given the same scenario I would go with the same method that you use and combine Matrix and CE Image to apply watermarks on an ad-hoc basis. That combination sounds like it should both work well and do everything that you need it to do. If it aint broke, don't fix it! ;)

I think the only benefit you may get to using Channel Images is the ability to upload multiple files at once rather than one per row but unless you have a *lot* of images per entry and this is really becoming a burden then I honestly think the extra work in changing things and the time in doing so wouldn't be worth the extra benefit.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. Your comment ("unless you have a _lot_ of images per entry") brings up a related issue. 

(BTW, the max # of images per entry is in the low teens.) 

I'm also working on improving overall performance on this site, which has been frustrating and sluggish. That slowness has affected image uploading and screen refreshes for navigation to image directories, etc. Instead of blaming my image solution, I need to keep focus on slow performance overall. Prolly need to postpone this search for a better solution (_hey! maybe CI will fix it!_) until I've slain my performance dragons.

Comment: Have you tried seeing what the Output Profiler returns? Admin > System Administration > Output & Debugging. Or better yet the [EE Debug Toolbar](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ee-debug-toolbar) will give you a clear picture of things like memory usage and load times. See if that provides an insight into those performance issues. Regarding the multi-upload however it seems that it is possible with Matrix afterall using [Matrix Multi Upload](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix-multi-upload).

Comment: Matrix Multi Upload. THANKS! Gonna try that. EE Debug Toolbar. Well, on my local install, got weird behavior w toolbar. Am in the midst of site update, so I may try it again afterwards. Gratefully,